# Group creation UI object in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, controls

I have this code. I would like to make it more compact. Is it possible to add the groups similar controls?

```
UILabel *controlFreeName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
controlFreeName.frame = CGRectMake(40.0f, 70.0f, 120.0f, 50.0f);
controlFreeName.text = @"Free";

UILabel *controlNoFreeName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
controlNoFreeName.frame = CGRectMake(40.0f, 110.0f, 120.0f, 50.0f);
controlNoFreeName.text = @"No free";

UILabel *controlEquipmentName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
controlEquipmentName.frame = CGRectMake(40.0f, 150.0f, 120.0f, 50.0f);
controlEquipmentName.text = @"Equipment";

UILabel *controlTypeName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
controlTypeName.frame = CGRectMake(40.0f, 190.0f, 180.0f, 50.0f);
controlTypeName.text = @"Type";
```

Comment: You could use a for loop, and a NSArray with all the "textes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
NSArray * myArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Test1",@"Test2",@"Test2", nil];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    UILabel * myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10*5*i, 10*5*i, 100, 100)];
    myLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
    int r = arc4random() % 255;
    int g = arc4random() % 255;
    int b = arc4random() % 255;
    myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1];
    [self.view addSubview: myLabel];
}
```

[image]